# Laravel Ajax Call Works Local but Not on Server

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, xampp

My Laravel Ajax call works locally with XAMPP and Apache, but not on the server (NGINX). All similar questions to this topic could not solve my problem. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

**Controller**

```
<?php

public function readHSauswahl(Request $request)
{
    $data = Message::where('name', '=', $request->title)->get();

    return response()->json($data);
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/readHSauswahl', 'AjaxController@readHSauswahl');
```

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url:'{!!URL::to('/readHSauswahl')!!}',
    dataType: "json",
    data:{'title':hochschule_name},
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
...
```

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: Have u change APP_URL in your .env file on server

Comment: did you use jquery cdn?If yes means check the http

Comment: the error is "cannot read property..." of my jquery object. the APP_URL is my server url

Comment: all other routes are working

Comment: did you warp your jquery code in ```$(function(){ })``` ? Sometimes we miss silly things

Comment: yes i wraped it. it is confusing, because on my localhost it works

Comment: the problem is, my variable in data does not arrive at the controller..